# stanford corenlp java sdk for Android

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am looking to use java sdk in Android app for text processing and bucketing those under some category.
but I see corenlp java sdk size is 371MB (version 3.7.0), which is not feasible in Android app, as size is very less than this and can not afford to have more app size.
Is it possible that only subset of nlp can be availed?

Answer (score 0):

Could you describe what you want to do with Stanford CoreNLP? And what size do you need to get things down to?  You can remove some code and resources, but the more you remove the more functionality you will lose.

UPDATE: Something to keep in mind, the code and dependencies are ~10 MB.  Most of that 350+ MB is resources that are only needed at run time.  You could definitely cut down the 10 MB if you are only using a subset.

Couldn't you put the resources in expansion files which allow up to 4 GB.  You could still remove some resources that are not necessary.

Though another serious problem is it appears that Android apps have a small RAM limit.  It may be challenging to get under 30 MB of RAM usage.

Comment: we mainly looking to process text entered by user under and try to categorize the entire text into one category, so here might be using some text mining algo. So for this specific task, is there a way to get a subset of code and resouces from 371MB, and the final sdk(jar or aar) size to be around 30-40 MB or less? Here I want to integrate sdk into android app, so not sure how to use expansion file.

Comment: I think you may have a lot of trouble getting down to that size.  But yes you can just select a few classes and the necessary resources and just use those rather than the full 371 MB.  You will have to compile a subset of the code that is needed for the classes you want and extract the necessary resources from the various jars.  The source code is available on GitHub: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP